# How to implement dialog that help users to know the app features?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I need to Implement the dialoges given in Image to introduce attributes of App, I couldn't find the way to implement it yet.

[image]

[image]

I have tried Firebase InAppMessaging but it's automatically being displayed just after the App starts. What I need is the Message dialog should display after a button gets clicked.
the code I putted in the button.OnclickListener

```
FirebaseInAppMessaging.getInstance().triggerEvent("CompaignId");
```

[Link to Firebase InAppMessaging Docs from where I get the given code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/modify-message-behavior?authuser=0&platform=android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [BubbleShowCase](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/7119) to achieve your dialog.

**How to use it in the simplest way:**

```
BubbleShowCaseBuilder(this) //Activity instance
            .title("foo") //Any title for the bubble view
            .targetView(view) //View to point out
            .show() //Display the ShowCase
```

And if you will read more in the library page you can find info about making a custom dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can use full-screen dialog with transparent background and show whatever feature you have to show
e.g

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
dialog.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of libraries out there, but if you want a google like showcase, you can use [ShowCaseView](https://github.com/outlander24/ShowcaseView)

```
    ShowcaseViewBuilder showcaseViewBuilder;
    showcaseViewBuilder = ShowcaseViewBuilder.init(this)
            .setTargetView(fab)
            .setBackgroundOverlayColor(0xdd4d4d4d)
            .setRingColor(0xcc8e8e8e)
            .setRingWidth((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()))
            .setMarkerDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_up), Gravity.LEFT)
            .addCustomView(R.layout.description_view, Gravity.TOP)
            .addCustomView(R.layout.skip_layout)
            .setCustomViewMargin((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 70, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
```